# Passing value into callback from Parent Component to Child without Binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component built like so, that takes in a callback function from its Parent component. When the onClick fires, it calls the callback with a value from the items being mapped over:

```
class Child extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map((el, idx) => {
          return <section onClick={() = this.props.cb(el.val)}></section>
        }
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

What I'm wondering is how I can accomplish passing a value from that `map` to the callback without using this syntax `() => this.props.cb(item.val)` or binding a value to the callback. I can't just pass the callback to `onClick` because it fires immediately with the value, either.

The current syntax works but breaks the rules I have setup in my linter.

Comment: see https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#lists-of-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to binding in `render` is breaking out a new component which takes the callback and the value to be passed:

```
class Section extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.val)
  }
  render() {
    return <section onClick={this.handleClick}></section>
  }
}
```

(I would suggest just disabling that lint rule, though)